# In many to many relationships, why is there a need to use a intermediate table in SSAS/Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, ssas, ssas-tabular

In powerBI/SSAS tabular; what would be a valid modelling decision to have a relationship as

**TableX** *--- 1 **TableY** 1--- * **TableZ**

Instead of: **TableX** * --- * **TableZ**

I see this in an old model, and I can't see why a direct many to many relationship wouldn't work?
[image]

Comment: Hey @chicago1988, is there any other query?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delayed response.
Can you please confirm what is the compatibility of this model as :

Tabular models at the 1500 and higher compatibility level deployed to Azure Analysis Services, SQL Server 2019 and later Analysis Services, and Power BI Premium support many-to-many relationships.

For lower models, earlier we had to create those bridge tables